# Parent Object In Mongoid Embedded Relation Extensions

Tags: mongoid, mongoid3, embedded-documents

Given a simple embedded relationship with an extension like this:

```
class D
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :es do
    def m
      #...
    end
  end
end

class E
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :d
end
```

You can say things like this:

```
d = D.find(id)
d.es.m
```

Inside the extension's `m` method, how do access the specific `d` that we're working with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm answering this myself for future reference. If anyone has an official and documented way of doing this, please let me know.

---

After an hour or so of Googling and reading (and re-reading) the Mongoid documentation, I turned to the Mongoid source code. A bit of searching and guesswork lead me to `@base` and its accessor method `base`:

```
  embeds_many :es do
    def m
      base
    end
  end
```

and then you can say this:

```
d = D.find(id)
d.es.m.id == id # true
```

`base` is [documented](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Relations/Binding:base) but the documentation is only there because it is defined using `attr_reader :base` and documentation generated from `attr_reader` calls isn't terribly useful. `base` also works with `has_many` associations.

---

How did I figure this out? The [documentation on extensions](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#common) mentions `@target` in an example:

```
embeds_many :addresses do
  #...
  def chinese
    @target.select { |address| address.country == "China"}
  end
end
```

`@target` isn't what we're looking for, `@target` is the array of embedded documents itself but we want what that array is inside of. A bit of grepping about for `@target` led me to `@base` (and the corresponding `attr_reader :base` calls) and a quick experiment verified that `base` is what I was looking for.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: With Rails you almost always have to read the source code to figure out WTF it is doing, this is a bit absurd but it is the truth. Beware, the Rails source can be pretty horrific at times. Check the [ActiveModel](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serialization.html#method-i-serializable_hash) method and the [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#method-i-serializable_hash) override. Then look at how the [`attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) method works.